# EXPO Receiving Notifications works when the application is in the background/foreground, but not when the application is killed

Tags: android, react-native, notifications, expo

I just learned about notifications in the expo, now I have successfully sent notifications and I have also managed to get data from the notifications I sent, the problem is, if the application is in background or foreground, `addNotificationResponseReceivedListener` is working properly (redirect to another page), but if I close the application, and I receive a notification, then I press the notification, the application opens but the `addNotificationResponseReceivedListener` function is not running, I try this in a standalone application

what i’m using:

```
“expo”: “~40.0.0”,
“expo-notifications”: “^0.9.0”,
```

here’s my example code in Home.js:

```
componentDidMount() {
    //another code..
    Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(
      this._handleNotificationResponse
    );
  }

_handleNotificationResponse = (response) => {
    console.log(
      "CONSOLE FROM NOTIF: " +
        JSON.stringify(response.notification.request.content.data.from)
    );
    if (response.notification.request.content.data.from== "GEMASS") {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("goToPage", {
        //another code...
      });
    } else {
    }
  };
```

here’s my file tree:

```
App.js
Components
   - Home.js
```

and here’s my terminal looks like when i run on expo client:
[clickme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRAgN.png)

can you guys help me? it means a lot :)

Comment: Do you still have this issue, while I am having the same problem

Comment: Yes i still have this issue, if you solved this problem, can you please inform me? thanks a lot

Comment: Only thing I found is that it is a known issue: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/9866#issuecomment-743454778